# How to mutate with SWR only for specific ID?

Tags: typescript, axios, next.js, swr

I've tried to look everywhere online and I can't seem to find any documentation on this which is strange because I thought it would be a popular need.

If we are trying to for example get the post with a specific id:

```
const { data } = useSWR(`/api/post/${id}`, fetcher)
```

And then maybe we have a form that edits the post, when we do mutate:

```
mutate(`/api/post/${id}`)
```

To force revalidation on a specific id, nothing happens. What would be the correct way to do it in this case?

And just to mention, doing SWR fetching without an id and something like /api/comments, where all the comments are fetched, then mutate has no problem revalidating when doing `mutate('/api/comments')`

Hopefully this made sense. What i'm basically trying to achieve is, to do a POST request after updating a post with some id, and then I want to re-render the page with the updated data.

I'm getting the impression that mutate doesn't recognize the key when the id value is dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just import **mutate** function from the hook, its bounded with that key.

```
const { data, mutate } = useSWR(`/api/post/${id}`, fetcher)
```

then just call **mutate()**

Comment: I just tried that, and it doesn't seem to work. I see a re-render but it still seems to have the old values cached.

Comment: can you add code where you are updating the post, here's where I get code from btw https://swr.vercel.app/docs/mutation#bound-mutate